# Querying data by time in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle in which data is inserted from different sources. In 2014, we discovered that some sources were not inserting the time stamp with the date, we however fixed them and now all sources insert data in proper format, example `05/04/2015 4:30:42 PM`

Using a SQL query, we want to divide the data into 3 types, morning shift, evening shift and no shift (for data without the time stamp).

Morning shift will be between `00:00:00` and `14:30:00`

Evening shift will be between `14:31:00` and `23:59:00`

I have written the query in 2 different ways as follows:

(a)

```
 CASE
        WHEN TO_DATE(DATEANDTIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')) AND (TO_DATE ('14:30:00', 'HH24:MI:SS'))
        THEN
           'MORNING SHIFT'
        WHEN TO_DATE(DATEANDTIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('14:31:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')) AND  (TO_DATE ('23:59:00', 'HH24:MI:SS'))
        THEN
           'EVENING SHIFT'
        ELSE
          'NO SHIFT'
     END SHIFT
```

(b)

```
CASE
        WHEN DATEANDTIME BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')) AND (TO_DATE ('14:30:00', 'HH24:MI:SS'))
        THEN
           'MORNING SHIFT'
        WHEN DATEANDTIME BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('14:31:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')) AND  (TO_DATE ('23:59:00', 'HH24:MI:SS'))
        THEN
           'EVENING SHIFT'
        ELSE
          'NO SHIFT'
     END SHIFT
```

Query (a) returns an error `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected` but Query (b) displays data with everything going to `NO SHIFT`

Sample data of the table is as follows of the `dateandtime` field:

```
05/04/2015 10:43
05/04/2015 16:52
05/04/2015 19:27
11/04/2009
```

Kindly guide me to the correct query and what am I doing wrong, the same conditions works in `TOAD` fine.

Comment: What is the data type of `dateandtime`?

Comment: The data type is `DATE`

Comment: Oracle does not store dates in any particular format, such as "2014-03-21 12:00:00" -- that is only for display purposes.

Comment: The seconds are always 00 in the dates, are they? If not, is 14:30:01 in the morning or the evening shift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the value to a string and do the comparison as strings:

```
(case when to_char(dateandtime, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '00:00' and '14:30'
      then 'MORNING SHIFT'
      when to_char(dateandtime, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '14:31' and '23:59'
      then 'EVENING SHIFT'
      else 'NO SHIFT'
 end) as SHIFT
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks. `to_char` crossed over my mind but didn't try it.